# How to plot only certain parts of list regarding a condition?

Tags: plotting

I have two lists which I transposed. Now, I need to ListPlot only pairs where both numbers are greater than 0 and skip those with at least 0 in pair. E.g.: to plot {1,5}, not to plot {0,20} etc.
Can you help me to figure it out?

```
x = {1, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
y = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60};
p = Transpose[{x, y}];
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Select` with `FreeQ[0]` as the selector function:

```
selected = Select[FreeQ[0]] @ p
```

> {{1, 5}, {5, 10}, {3, 15}}

```
ListPlot[selected]
```

[image]

You can also use `Cases` or `DeleteCases` or `Pick` or `ReplaceAll` as follows:

```
Cases[{Except[0]..}] @ p
DeleteCases[{0,_}|{_,0}] @ p
Pick[p, Unitize[Times @@@ p], 1]
p /. {0,_}|{_,0} -> Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped a lot. :-)